# Extracting a specific JSON in FLASK API

Tags: python, json, api, flask

I have a specific JSON format in the following form:

```
{
      "ts":"12233321",
      "s":
            { 
            "s1":"12.2232",
            "s2":"23.4445",
            "s3":"12.2232"
            },
      "e":
            {
            "e1":"23.12312",
            "e2":"12.33445",
            "e3":"12.33445"
            }
}
```

I have a flask api where for a specific url i am trying to get this json and then store :
ts: in a variable
's' and 'e' in numpy arrays.
How can Do that?

My Flask API looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

# In[ ]:

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=["POST"])
def root_dir():
    {
     data = request.get_json()
     (Now write code to get what i need from the data to get ts, S, E)
     return ts,s,e
}
```

ts: single variable
s: numpy array
e: numpy array

Comment: Have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html to read json using pandas. Add a desired output for a fuller answer.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to retrieve the values from the dict object. For the ones that are inner dict, take the `.values()` and use `dtype=float`

```
ts_array = np.array([values["ts"]], dtype=int)  # [12233321]
s_array = np.array(list(values["s"].values()), dtype=float)  # [12.2232 23.4445 12.2232]
e_array = np.array(list(values["e"].values()), dtype=float)  # [23.12312 12.33445 12.33445]
```

Comment: But how will i use the request in teh flask? I am able to unwrap the json however i do not know how will i use the json request api to access the json and unwrap it.

Comment: @KathanVyas I don't understand at all , try to explicit it by editing your question post maybe

Comment: @KathanVyasSo your question is, how to read JSON from Flask request ?

Comment: So I have used request.get_json() to get the json. what can I do next to get the values I want from that json? I haev edited a little so you can see what I am talking

Comment: @KathanVyas you can do `request.get_json()` or just `request.json` in fact? Do `prind(data)` to see what you got ;)

Comment: Print(data) prints the json as it is. I want to store the key and values in separate arrays

Comment: @KathanVyas maybe you can use my code now from my answer